# Magento: How i setup paypal payflow and paypal express with different paypal account

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.7

How I enable in Magento  "Paypal Payflow Pro" and "PayPal Express" using different paypal accounts?

In Magento 1.8 when I enabled "Paypal Payflow Pro" automatically enabled "PayPal Express" using the same credentials and disabled the others Paypal payments module. and If I try to checkout using the "PayPal Express" I received the error below

```
"PayPal gateway rejected the request. Not signed up for this tender type"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in magento. If you want to do so you need custom code for it. I have also configure the Payflow pro and it is showing the same error.You need to contact paypal support.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly do not know the ramifications of this, but if you want to try setting the PayPal Express settings that are automatically configured when setting up PayFlowPro, you can use `Inspect Element` on the disabled `Configure` button.

```
<button type="button" class="button disabled open" id="payment_express_checkout-head" onclick="paypalToggleSolution.call(this, 'payment_express_checkout', 'http://some.url'); return false;" disabled=""><span class="state-closed">Configure</span><span class="state-opened">Close</span></button>
```

Just remove the `disabled` portion in Firebug/Dev Tools and you can then click the button and change the settings.